# Iteration of $\log(z) / \sqrt{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, special-functions

The complex function $\log(z) / \sqrt{z}$ is a curiosity that I find interesting since one can express $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ as $\log(-1) / \sqrt{-1} = \pi$.

My question is, what is the significance of the following complex values?

$\log(5.06982105...+i\times2.16077849...) / \sqrt{5.06982105...+i\times2.16077849...}
= $
$\qquad0.746670201...+i\times0.0226809289...$

$\log(0.746670201...+i\times0.0226809289...) / \sqrt{0.746670201...+i\times0.0226809289...}
=$
$\qquad -0.336892113...+i\times0.0402541188...$

$\log(-0.336892113...+i\times0.0402541188...) / \sqrt{-0.336892113...+i\times0.0402541188...}
=$
$\qquad 5.06982105...+i\times2.16077849...$

It appears that the repeated iteration of this function almost always eventually leads to this cycle of three values.

I was expecting these values to be somehow related to the Lambert $W$ function, but I cannot even find such a connection, nor any other connection to known constants, functions, or values.

Also, why would this cycle have three values rather than two values?

For the record, there is one complex number that satisfies $\log(z) / \sqrt{z} = z$:

$e^{(-2/3)W(-3/2)}$

But when one begins with randomly chosen complex numbers, the iteration of this function leads not to this value, but to the cycle of three values given above.

Comment: When I iterate this function (using Mathematica) with a random initial condition, I find that about half the time it settles into the same 3-point periodic cycle you found, and half the time it falls into the complex conjugate of that cycle. Coloring those initial conditions in the complex plane which lead to your cycle white and the ones that lead to its complex conjugate black yields a very nice fractal boundary between the two sets.

Comment: By the way, I find that your fixed point involving the Lambert function is an unstable fixed point, which explains why iteration from a random initial value does not end up there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on John Barber's comment, I plotted the fractal he mentioned using the [domain coloring](http://www.mai.liu.se/~hanlu09/complex/domain_coloring-unicode.html) below:

[image]

The above image assigns a color to every point in the complex plane (only $[-10,10]$ of each axis is shown). Plotting $\log(z)/\sqrt z$ gives:

[image]

And iterating 100 times gives:

[image]

There appears to be 5 colors: yellow, dark yellow, brown, dark brown, and red (two shades, probably). This suggests that after infinite iterations, there can only be those few values. From the original domain coloring, it's clear that yellow and dark brown are complex conjugates, dark yellow and brown are conjugates, and the two reds are conjugates.

Someone with more skill, time, and patience can probably explain the fractal domain boundaries.

Comment: Yup, that looks like what I got. I believe the ends of the "little red moustache" shape are the Lambert W function unstable fixed point and its complex conjugate.

Comment: @JohnBarber and Victor Liu, thank you very much for your research and graphing! Investigating further, I have noticed the curious phenomenon that log(z) / z^x appears to behave like log(z) / z^(1/2) when 1/2 <= x < 1, but appears to converge to a fixed point when x < 1/2 ! Perhaps someone could produce graphs for x = 2/3, 1/3, 3/4, 1/4 to test this phenomenon? TIA

Comment: I have uploaded a video to youtube of $x=0 .. 64/64$: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDJZ0Q61Fec](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDJZ0Q61Fec)